# Calling Yahoo Weather API from VoiceXML

Tags: api, yahoo, weather, vxml, voicexml

I'm trying to make a voice weather system with voiceXML and the Yahoo Weather API. To develop my program I'm using voxeo evolution.

To call the Weather API I'm using the `data` vxml tag with an `srcexpr` because I need a dynamic URL (the program asks the user for a city to check weather in).

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1">
    <form id="mainMenu">
        <field name="City">
            <prompt> 
                Please, name a spanish city.
            </prompt>

            <grammar src="city.grammar"/>
        </field>
        <!-- code taken from the javascript example of the yahoo weather api -->
        <script>
        <![CDATA[
            var callbackFunction = function(data) {
                var wind = data.query.results.channel.wind;
                alert(wind.chill);
            };
        ]]>
        </script>

        <data srcexpr="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text='"+City+", spain')&callback=callbackFunction"/>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

The program doesn't work because of the `data` tag to connect to the weather API, but I don't know why. Do someone know why is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem making a php script to connect to the yahoo api and calling it using `submit` tag in VoiceXML.

```
<?php
    $City = $_REQUEST["City"];
    $Day = $_REQUEST["Day"];
    $BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    $yql_query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="('.$City.', spain)") and u="c"';
    $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json";
    $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $yahooapi = curl_exec($session);
    $weather =  json_decode($yahooapi,true);

    $weather_resumen = $weather['query']['results']['channel']['item']['forecast'];

    $weather_today = $weather_resumen[0]['day'];
    // yahoo api returns an array with the weather for the next week ordered by
    // day (0 -> today, 1 -> tomorrow...). Function get_day gets the index of
    // the day the user said
    $index_weather = get_day($weather_today, $Day);
    $condition_index = $weather_resumen[$index_weather]['code'];
    $weather_condition = $cond_met[intval($condition_index)];
    $min_temp = $weather_resumen[$index_weather]['low'];
    $max_temp = $weather_resumen[$index_weather]['high'];

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
?>
<vxml version="2.1" xml:lang="es-ES">
    <form id="form_main">
        <block>
            <prompt>
                The weather for <?php echo $Day ?> in <?php echo $City ?> is <?php echo $weather_condition ?>. The lowest temperature will be <?php echo $min_temp ?> and the highest <?php echo $max_temp ?>.
                <break/>
            </prompt>
        </block>
    </form>
</vxml>
```